# I have got a problem with reading binary file into array of structures in c

Tags: c

Here is part of my code:
Here I want to transfer already saved `.bin` file into a new database structure `student s`, but it is not transferring more than one member of a structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
    int id;
    int pnum;
}student;
int count = 0;
void swap(student* s1, student* s2) {
    student* temp;
    temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}

void sort(student* s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            if (strcmp((s + i)->name, (s + j)->name) > 0) {
                student temp = *(s + i);
                *(s + i) = *(s + j);
                *(s + j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void addInf(student* s) {
    printf("\t==================================Adding information=====================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tPlease input following information: \n");
    printf("\tName: ");
    scanf("%s", (s + count)->name);
    printf("\tDate of birth (yyyymmdd): ");
    scanf("%4d%2d%2d", &(s + count)->year, &(s + count)->month, &(s + count)->date);
    printf("\tStudent ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &(s + count)->id);
    printf("\tPhone number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(s + count)->pnum);
    count++;
    printf("\tEntry succeded.\n");
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
}

void print(student* s) {
    printf("\t\tName: %s\n", s->name);
    printf("\t\tBidthday: %d/%02d/%02d\n", s->year, s->month, s->date);
    printf("\t\tID: %d\n", s->id);
    printf("\t\tPhone number: %d\n", s->pnum);
}

void delInf(student* s, int n) {
    int com;
    printf("\t=================================Deleting information====================================\n\n");
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");

    char name[20];
    printf("\t\tPlease input name of the student that you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(name, (s + i)->name)) == 0) {
            printf("\t\tInformation that you want to delete\n");
            print((s + i));

            for (int j = i; j < count; j++) {
                *(s + i) = *(s + i + 1);
                count--;
                printf("\t\tInformation was succesfully deleted.\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

void searchByID(student* s) {
    int key;
    printf("\t======================================Searching by ID====================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (key == (s + i)->id) {
            break;
        }
    }
    print((s + i));
}
void searchByName(student* s) {
    char key[20];
    int i;
    int size, check = 0;
    printf("\t======================================Searching by Name==================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tEnter Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &key);
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(key, (s + i)->name) == 0) {
            print((s + i));
        }
    }
}

void searchByBirthDate(student* s) {
    int key, command;
    int i;
    printf("\t================================Searching by Birthdate================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t1.By Date\t\t 2.By Month\t\t 3.By Year\t\t 4.By All\n");
    printf("\t\tCommand: ");
    scanf("%d", &command);
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
    if (command == 1) {
        printf("Enter date: ");
        scanf("%2d", &key);
        printf("\t\tStudent with same date\n");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (key == (s + i)->date) {
                printf("\t\t---------%d----------\n\n", i + 1);
                print((s + i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (command == 2) {
        printf("\t\tEnter month: ");
        scanf("%2d", &key);
        printf("\t\tStudent with same month\n");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (key == (s + i)->month) {
                printf("\t\t---------%d----------\n\n", i + 1);
                print((s + i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (command == 3) {
        printf("\t\tEnter year: ");
        scanf("%4d", &key);
        printf("\t\tStudent with same year\n");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (key == (s + i)->year) {
                printf("\t\t---------%d----------\n\n", i + 1);
                print(s + i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (command == 4) {
        int yy, mm, dd;
        printf("\t\tEnter birthdate: ");
        scanf("%4d%2d%2d", &yy, &mm, &dd);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (yy == (s + i)->year && mm == (s + i)->month && dd == (s + i)->date) {
                break;
            }
        }
        print(s + i);
    }
}

void printTable(student* s) {
    printf("\t============================================Table========================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tName\t\t\tBirthday\t\t\tStudent ID\t\t\tPhone number\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\t%d. %s\t\t\t\t%d/%d/%d\t\t\t%d\t\t\t0%d\n\n", i + 1, (s + i)->name, (s + i)->year, (s + i)->month, (s + i)->date, (s + i)->id, (s + i)->pnum);
    }
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
}

void search(student* s) {
    printf("\t=========================================Search==========================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tAvailable commands: \n");
    printf("\t\t1. Search by name\t\t\t2. Search by ID\n\t\t3. Search by birthday\n");
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tPlease choose command: ");
    int com;
    scanf("%d", &com);

    switch (com) {
    case 1: searchByName(s);
        break;
    case 2: searchByID(s);
        break;
    case 3: searchByBirthDate(s);
        break;
    }
}

void menu() {
    printf("\n\t======================================MENU===============================================\n");
    printf("\t\tAvailable commands: \n");
    printf("\t\t1. Add Student\t\t\t2.Delete student\n\t\t3. Find student\t\t\t4. Table of all students\n");
    printf("\t\t5. Transfer information from binary file\n\t\t6. Save information into binary file.\n\t\t0. Exit\n\n");
    printf("\t=========================================================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\tPlease choose command: ");
}

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* fpr;

    printf("\t\tEnter a name of binary file that you want to create: ");
    char filename[20];
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    strcat(filename, ".bin");

    fp = fopen(filename, "ab");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\t\tUnable to open the file.\nError\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("\t\t\tFile %s successfuly created\n\n", filename);
    int iCount;
    int n, c;
    student* s;
    printf("\t\tPlease enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n\n");

    s = (student*)calloc(n, sizeof(student));
    int quit = 1;
    while (quit) {
        menu();
        scanf("%d", &c);
        printf("\n");

        switch (c) {
        case 0:
            quit = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            addInf(&s);
            break;
        case 2:
            delInf(&s, n);
            break;

        case 3:
            search(&s);

            break;
        case 4:
            if (count == 0) printf("\t\tThere is no any given information yet.\n\n");
            else printTable(&s);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("\t\tEnter a name or path of file that you want to open: ");
            char readfilename[30];
            scanf("%s", &readfilename);
            strcat(readfilename, ".bin");
            fpr = fopen(readfilename, "rb+");
            if (fpr == NULL) {
                printf("\t\tUnable to open the file.\nError\n");
                break;
            }
            else printf("\t\tFile %s successfuly opened for reading\n", readfilename);
            printf("\t\t\ttransfering binary data from %s into database\n", readfilename);
            while ((fread(&s, sizeof(student), 1, fpr)) == 1) {
                count++;
            }
            printf("\t\t%d student information was successfuly transferred\n", count);
            break;
        case 6:

            iCount = fwrite(&s, sizeof(student), count, fp);
            if (iCount != count) printf("Information could be missed in %s file\n", filename);
            else printf("\t\tAll information was successfuly copied into %s file", filename);
        }
        sort(&s);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "its not transferring more than one member of structure"? Please provide a [mre] to also convince other users, e.g. me.

Comment: I have edited my code so can you check it now?

Comment: PS. That's a minimal reproducible example

Comment: OK. Then explain what it is demonstrating. What makes you think that "its not transferring more than one member of structure"? (By the way, that is one amazing edit which you describe as "corrected grammar and added some formatting".)

Comment: There are some issues with your code. 1) `sort` is not defined anywhere. 2) `addInf` and `printTable` are called with the wrong arguments.

Comment: That is not my full code. that is why there is no function `sort` is not defined anywhere. `addInf` and `printTable` are working well. I have got a problem only with the transferring section. When I try to transfer its transferring only a last member of a structure and other information is just garbage values.

Comment: Now I have uploaded all code with all functions so check this one

Comment: `s` is a pointer to `student`. Why are you reading into (and writing from) `&s`? I was expecting `s` there.

Comment: When I am using `s` it gives an error: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF93237F501 (ucrtbased.dll) in ch8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001007A697A41.`

Comment: I removed all `&` operators that were applied to variables of type `char *`, and at first sight, it seems to work fine. Unless of course I choose to read a file that is bigger than the memory allocated. Needs some bounds checking.

Comment: when I removed all `&` operators as used it worked also but the problem is that program read only one member of struct that was saved before and all the others shows `0` or garbage value

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS (38) of warnings message, several of which are critical.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same results..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enable warnings when compiling, and follow up on them!
This should tell you that `&s` is wrong in every place where you used it.
This causes your program to suffer from undefined behavior, which is a total pest when trying to debug your program!

Now then, on to the code that reads students from file:

```
while ((fread(s, sizeof(student), 1, fpr)) == 1) {
    count++;
}
```

Every student is read into the same memory area (pointed to by `s`). They overwrite each other, leaving only the last one read. Try `s + count` instead of `s`:

```
while ((fread(s + count, sizeof(student), 1, fpr)) == 1) {
    count++;
}
```